# SQL Query Return Entries with no Occurences in Other Table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, orders and customers, and I am trying to return the customerID and name of customers with no orders.

```
customers
customerID: integer
name: string

orders
orderID: integer
itemID: integer
customerID: integer
date: date
```

What I currently have is not returning any results:

```
SELECT customers.customerID, customers.fName, orders.date
FROM orders INNER JOIN customers
ON orders.customerID = customers.customerID
GROUP BY orders.customerID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
```

Comment: If you are trying to group by customer id and trying to print 3 columns, the query would not work in the first place. Read the basic logic of writing group by http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to accomplish this:

```
SELECT customers.customerID, customers.fName
FROM customers LEFT OUTER JOIN orders on customers.customerID = orders.customerID
WHERE orders.customerID IS NULL
```